# size of patches in meters

Tags: size, netlogo, patch

please, I'm using Netlogo to simulate a wireless sensor network, but I don't know how to convert the patch size to meter, for expmle in WSN we have to say covered area is 500*500 m2, how  to do that with patches please ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The size of patches in NetLogo is measured in... patches.

That is to say, they don't have an intrinsic size in real-world units unless you, the modeler, assigns them one. It's entirely up to you. If you decide that one patch represents one square meter, then that's what it is. But you don't need to tell that to NetLogo. It's purely a matter of convention and interpretation.

In your particular case, it would make sense to adopt the convention that one patch represents one square meter. If you then want the size of your world to be 500m×500m, you can adjust your model settings to make it 500 patches per 500 patches:

[image]

(Note that the "Patch size (measured in pixel)" field in the settings only tells NetLogo how big to make the patch appear on the screen. It doesn't affect the behaviour of your model in any way.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply,, so it is about assumptions ..

Answer (score 1):

Because you have to scale the real world down to fit it into the View window,  one patch represents whatever distance or area you want it to represent.    It's like opening a map in Google maps and asking how far one centimeter on the screen represents?  It could be anything.  NetLogo doesn't know and doesn't care.

If you right click the View window in the interface and select "edit" you can see that the default size for a patch is 13 pixels, but you can over-ride that and make it whatever you want.  So one "patch" could be 1 cm x 1 cm if you want.  It's entirely up to you.   The default size of a patch is pretty small.  If the patch gets too small it's hard to click on or even see, but that may not matter to you.

If you're importing a background image of a map of the real world, using the import-drawing command, NetLogo will have no idea what the scale of the map is. There is no GIS function that I know of to automatically set the scale of the map. NetLogo can't tell an image of your yard or from an image of this section of the Milky Way galaxy.

As the User Dictionary says about import-drawing,

> [it] Reads an image file into the drawing, scaling it to the size of
>   the world, while retaining the original aspect ratio of the image. The
>   image is centered in the drawing...Agents cannot sense the drawing...

In the View editor ( or in your code) you can set min-pxcor and max-pxcor, say, to whatever you want,  and over-ride the default View settings of a world that is 32 patches wide and high to whatever you want it to be.  You could make the view be 100 patches wide if that's more convenient.

But if NetLogo tries to fit 100 patches into the width of your View window, the size of the view window **on your computer screen** will be that number of patches wide times the number of pixels in a patch, so the viewing window might not even fit on your computer screen and you might only see the top left corner or it,   and you'd need to change the patch size down to 3 pixels or something to fit that many patches on your screen.    Try it out and see.

The size of the view on your screen will change from the default of about 10 centimeters to whatever is required to fit that many patches of that patch size in that window.

Comment: I didn't realize that Nicolas Payette was answering this question at the same time I was so my answer is only another way of saying what he said.   Sorry for the redundancy!

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply,, so it is about assumptions ..